# Is it possible to delete "Windows Defender" from Registry via a CMD command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, registrykey

```
PowerRun_x64.exe "Reg.exe" delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Testing" /f
```

The above can delete "Testing" in "Windows Defender". 
However, the following cannot delete "Windows Defender" although it can be deleted via PowerRun's GUI.

```
PowerRun_x64.exe "Reg.exe" delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" /f
```

Is it possible to delete "Windows Defender" via a CMD command line instead of the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

With a little effort, and help from GitHub. Note that, this pertains to Windows 10 1903.

**Windows 10 Privacy Guide - 1903 Update**

https://github.com/adolfintel/Windows10-Privacy

Scroll down to the section, Removing Windows Defender.
You will need to download a program from this site (from the author), install_wim_tweak.exe, which needs to be copied to the System32 folder, or a folder that is in your environment variables.

As noted, make sure you switch off the Defender icon in the system tray before removing Defender.

Please note, the site warns, that you may break Windows, and Windows update, implementing its procedures. Be careful.

Hope this assist.

Thanks and regards,

-njc